# Reliable way to detect new Int64 and Float64 dtypes and map to older ones

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know what the new dtypes are called, but when I create a df like

```py
xdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=pd.Float64Dtype),
        "b": [True, False, True, False],
    }
)
```

the dtype for `a` appears to be object:

```py
>>> xdf.dtypes
a    object
b      bool
dtype: object
```

Earlier (maybe on a different pandas version), it would show up and look like `Float64`, I believe. These types sometimes cause problems when using sklearn, so I'd like to convert them (`Int64`, `Float64`) back to classic float dtype to handle nulls in the meantime.

Is there a way to reliably detect that a dtype is one of the new kinds? It seems that for some versions I coud get the string representation of the dtype and see if it starts with a capital letter, but I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to detect the new one (and ultimately convert back to the old one). Preferably besides looking at all of the contents of the series and deciding from all of the types.

I have

```
pandas version: 1.4.4
numpy version: 1.21.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is using a function like this:

```
def change_dtype(series):
    
    if series.dtype == pd.Float64Dtype:
        return series.astype(float)
    
    if series.dtype == pd.Int64Dtype:
        return series.astype(int)
    
    return series
```

And then use it in all the columns of the dataframe that are of those types like this:

```
def fix_dtype_dataframe(df):
    new_num_cols = [col for col in xdf.columns if df[col].dtype in [pd.Float64Dtype, pd.Int64Dtype]]

    def fix_dtype_series(series):
    
        if series.dtype == pd.Float64Dtype:
            return series.astype(float)

        if series.dtype == pd.Int64Dtype:
            return series.astype(int)

        return series


    df[new_num_cols] = df[new_num_cols].apply(fix_dtype_series, axis=0)
    return df

xdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=pd.Float64Dtype),
        "b": [True, False, True, False],
    }
)


xdf = fix_dtype_dataframe(xdf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the version of pandas I have, though, it looks like it changes dtype to `object`. Do you know which versions of pandas your solution will work for?

Comment: I'm using the newer one 2.0.0. Sorry, didn't see you're using 1.4